# Error in accessing dist(folder created using Gulp depoly) on S3

Tags: angularjs, amazon-s3

I have upload dist folder(created after gulp deploy) on AWS S3 but got error in accessing some .json file. I am using triangular material design.It's working very well on localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the url in config file

```
$translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('app/examples/elements');
```

Url should be like above  if you have added any extra space after elements like this

`$translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('app/examples/elements/');`

then remove it